# Pythonnet Runtime Error using C# dll (Database Incompatibility)

Tags: c#, python, clr, python.net, pythonnet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGDhr.png)I am using a C# dll using pythonnet on python 2.7.13 (which uses other dll files and .mdb database files) to make some technical calculations. This dll files does not have a good documentation (only namespaces, class and method names). Well the program in most PC Works Fine but in all office computers it throws a runtime Error from Dll files (my doubt is connection with database). This dll files are compiled to target .NET 4.0 (in office computers is installed .NET 4.7.1 or other versions newer than 4.0) and EntityFramework is also being used (programs target 5.0 and this is a dll file in program folder, but in office computers is installed EntityFramework 6.2 tool). Microsoft database Engine 2010 is also installed in those computers.

In every other computer that I have tested the program it works perfectly. In office computers I found a group of input data for which program works, but anyway this is not correct because it should work also for the default data.

To make tests in office computers I have compiled python code using PyInstaller (I repeat, compiled version work fine in other PCs).

I am using .NET Reflector to decompile dll files and programs Exception to find the Error. The method that throws Exception is in the following code.

Thanks in advance!

```
public int LoadRanghiAmmessi(int[] vRanghi, string geometria)
{
    int index = 0;
    CrConnection connection = new CrConnection(this.PathDB);
    string query = "SELECT * FROM RanghiAmmessi WHERE (Geometria='" + geometria + "') ORDER BY NRanghi";
    OleDbDataReader recordset = connection.GetRecordset(query, @"\Coils.mdb;");
    if (!recordset.HasRows)
    {
        if (recordset != null)
        {
            recordset.Close();
        }
        query = "SELECT * FROM RanghiAmmessi WHERE (Geometria='*') ORDER BY NRanghi";
        recordset = connection.GetRecordset(query, @"\Coils.mdb;");
        while (recordset.Read())
        {
            vRanghi[index] = int.Parse(recordset["NRanghi"].ToString());
            index++;
        }
        if (recordset != null)
        {
            recordset.Close();
        }
    }
    return index;
}



public OleDbDataReader GetRecordset(string query, string NomeDB)
{
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + this.PathDB + NomeDB + "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123456";
    this.ChiudiConnessioni();
    this.conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, this.conn);
    try
    {
        this.ApriConnessione();
        return command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.Message.ToString();
        this.ChiudiConnessioni();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests I found out that the program is working also in other PC after declaring some objects like function parameters and after compiling running the program as compatible with Windows 7. Before the objects were created like variables and those variables were passed as parameters, (in this case, reasonably the first thought is that the problem is "pass by reference" mechanism and that some values are not inserted in the right mode, but this is not the case because:
   - the same exactly code did function very well in most PC (compatibility 
     problem)
   - the same exactly mechanism is used to specify the objects attributes and 
     to make calculations
In this conditions I would say that it is not clear where the problem was. In the first version installing the SQL Server Express made possible for the program to work well even without last modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... given the details that it works fine on "Other PC", I am guessing that the problem is your so-called database. I don't see in  any way, however, how anyone could be certain at what the problem is until it is solved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responde! Well, i would say that I am almost sure that the problem stand with database connection/IO, but what I want to find out is the compatibility issue so I can add this to the specifications of the program. This can also help me to fix the problem in "other PC". The database is structured in 3 Access .mdb files. The "other PC" have installed Microsoft office 2007/2003, but I don't think the problem is that configuration because I have done a test uninstalling M. Office from my PC and the program still Works Fine.

Comment: @JonadriBundo this stuff is probably to advacned for me. But this was my guess